# Javascript recursion completes before traversing the whole tree?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm working on a project where one exercise asks to traverse a data structure below and returning an array containing all the files (i.e. *.js, *.css):

```
var fileData = {
  dir : 'app',
  files : [
    'index.html',
    {
      dir : 'js',
      files: [
        'main.js',
        'app.js',
        'misc.js',
        {
          dir : 'vendor',
          files : [
            'jquery.js',
            'underscore.js'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      dir : 'css',
      files : [
        'reset.css',
        'main.css'
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I came up with a recursive solution so that when you call `listFiles` with parameter `fileData` it should return the desired array:

```
function listFiles(data) {
  var retval = [];
  var files;

  (function crawl(filedata) {
    files = filedata.files;

    if (typeof files !== 'undefined') {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (typeof files[i] === 'string') {
          retval.push(files[i]);
        } else {
          crawl(files[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  })(data);

  return retval;
}
```

However, when running the code it only returns *.js. This means in directory `app`, my program is supposed to traverse all three elements but after the recursive call on the second it does not go check the third (/css). Can anyone explain why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the `files` variable local to the recursive function. Otherwise, when you recurse, you're overwriting the value used in the caller.

```
function listFiles(data) {
  var retval = [];

  (function crawl(filedata) {
    var files = filedata.files;

    if (typeof files !== 'undefined') {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (typeof files[i] === 'string') {
          retval.push(files[i]);
        } else {
          crawl(files[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  })(data);

  return retval;
}
```

Comment: So I guess this is another example of JS having function scope? In my original code, `files` inside `crawl()` is actually a global var even though I had it declared in the parent function `listFiles()`?

Comment: It was a local variable, but the scope was the `listFiles()` function, not `crawl()`.

Comment: @Barmar - I want to return all the files under a given folder name. So for the file structure above if i pass 'js' as the folder name i should recursively return all the files that are under that folder. So i should return - 'main.js', 'app.js', 'misc.js', jquery.js' and 'underscore.js'. I tried in the same lines but having issues. Now my  function signature looks like this listFiles(data, folderName)

Comment: You need to first recurse to look for the starting folder. When you get there, call `listFiles` on that node to get all the files under it.