# Extract value from array recursively in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to extract the files in this structure recursively. I have done it for the first level, but can't proceed further.

```
var DirectoryTree = {
    dir: 'project1',
    files: [
        'proj.config', {
            dir: 'src',
            files: [
                'name.htm',
                'dept.htm',
                'salary.htm', {
                    dir: 'scripts',
                    files: [
                        'name.js',
                        'dept.js',
                        'salary.js'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            dir: 'project2',
            files: [
                'proj.config', {
                    dir: 'src',
                    files: [
                        'name.htm',
                        'dept.htm',
                        'salary.htm', {
                            dir: 'scripts',
                            files: [
                                'name.js',
                                'dept.js',
                                'salary.js'
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Below is the code I have till now. I am kind of stuck here. Can you help me to get the data from the next levels.

```
function listFiles(dirTree, subFolder){
    var fList=[];
    if(dirTree.files){
        for (var i=0;i<dirTree.files.length;i++){
            if(typeof dirTree.files[i] === 'string'){
                fList.push(dirTree.files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(dirTree.dir){
        return(listFiles(dirTree.dir, subFolder));
    }
    return fList;
}
```

Comment: 1.) Are you trying to get all the files? 2.) Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Also, you are trying to extract values from an ***object*** -- not an `Array`. Be precise. :)

Comment: yes. All the filenames.

Comment: *"2.) Why are you trying to do this?"* Smells like homework to me.

Comment: Also, your `DirectoryTree` doesn't have valid syntax according to JSFiddle. :P

Comment: Looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207496/javascript-recursion-completes-before-traversing-the-whole-tree

Answer (score 2):

You can do this recursively, like this

```
function getFiles(currentObject, result) {
    var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(currentObject),
        idx;
    if (type === "[object Object]") {
        for (idx in currentObject) {
            if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(idx) && idx === "files") {
                currentObject[idx].forEach(function(object) {
                    getFiles(object, result);
                });
            }
        }
    } else if (type === "[object Array]") {
        currentObject.forEach(function(object) {
            getFiles(object, result);
        });
    } else if (type === "[object String]") {
        result.push(currentObject);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getFiles(DirectoryTree, []))
```

**Output**

```
[ 'proj.config',
  'name.htm',
  'dept.htm',
  'salary.htm',
  'name.js',
  'dept.js',
  'salary.js',
  'proj.config',
  'name.htm',
  'dept.htm',
  'salary.htm',
  'name.js',
  'dept.js',
  'salary.js' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question today and solved it using a few underscore functions.
The format of your example is pretty weird, but I would advise again to use a recursive function for this type of reads:

```
function recursiveFuntion(collection){
    collection.forEach(function(model) { 
        //console.log(model.files); --> Or do whatever you need 
        if(model.files.length > 0){ 
            recursiveFunction(model); 
        }; 
     }); 
}; 

recursiveFuntion(DirectoryTree.files);
```

The benefit of the recursive function is that it is dynamic.
As you are not working with an array but with an object, you'll need to customise this code.
But this is the basic principle.