# Get the filenames from the folder structure with a specified folder name

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to solve a similar problem and running into issues.
[Javascript recursion completes before traversing the whole tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207496/javascript-recursion-completes-before-traversing-the-whole-tree).

I have the same function listFiles but with two parameters. The second parameter is the folder name that is passed to this function. The function should return the filenames that fall under the passed foldername. For eg. if the folder name passed is 'js' then the function should return 5 files i.e - main.js', 'app.js', 'misc.js', 'jquery.js' and 'underscore.js'. Here is the code i am trying to write to achieve the result -

```
function listSubfolder(fileSystem, subFolder){
            var result = [];
            for(var i=0; i<fileSystem.files.length; i++){
                if(typeof fileSystem.files[i] !== 'string') {
                    fileSystem = fileSystem.files[i];
                    findFiles(fileSystem);
                }
            }

        function findFiles(fileSystem) {
            var files = fileSystem.files;
            if (typeof files !== 'undefined') {
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof files[i] === 'string') {
                        result.push(files[i]);
                    } else {
                        findFiles(files[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems here. The first is scope.

You're passing a parameter `fileSystem` into the function (L1):

`function listSubfolder(fileSystem, subFolder){`

*but* you're redefining it within the function (L5):

`fileSystem = fileSystem.files[i];`

The same thing is happening on your `findFiles` function (L10) as well. You're specifying `fileSystem` again (which doesn't happen to break the original `fileSystem` object from `listSubFolder` but it may cause errors in the future) so I would rename that parameter as well.

The second problem now is you need to check if the files are from the specified sub folder (L4):

`if(typeof fileSystem.files[i] !== 'string' && fileSystem.files[i].dir === subFolder) {`

The final edit should look something like this:

```
function listSubfolder(fileSystem, subFolder){
    var result = [], 
        fArr;
    for(var i=0; i<fileSystem.files.length; i++){
        if(typeof fileSystem.files[i] !== 'string' && fileSystem.files[i].dir === subFolder) {
            fArr = fileSystem.files[i];
            findFiles(fArr);
        }
    }

    function findFiles(f) {
        var files = f.files;
        if (typeof files !== 'undefined') {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (typeof files[i] === 'string') {
                    result.push(files[i]);
                } else {
                    findFiles(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the code you provided is that you are not checking the current folder to see if you are within `subFolder`.  You can add an extra [Boolean](http://www.javascripture.com/Boolean) parameter to the `findFiles` method that tracks if you are in the specified subfolder or not.  Only if that is true should you add the files to `result`.

There's also a bug in your first loop where you were changing fileSystem each time through the loop.  You can just remove that loop though and have findFiles process the root folder like all the others.

```
function listSubfolder(fileSystem, subFolder){
  var result = [];

  function findFiles(fileSystem, inSubFolder) {
    var files = fileSystem.files;
    if (typeof files !== 'undefined') {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (typeof files[i] === 'string') {
          if (inSubFolder) {
            result.push(files[i]);
          }
        } else {
          var currentInSubFolder = (files[i].dir === subFolder);
          findFiles(files[i], inSubFolder || currentInSubFolder);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  findFiles(fileSystem, false);
  return result;
}
```